# Use Google Plus SDK with existing access token?

Tags: ios, google-plus

After a weird login flow I get the access token for Google Plus from my server.
I can successfully call `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=%@` to get information about the user and `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/%@?access_token=%@` to get the users' friends.

I want to use the native share dialog on `GPPShare`, but since I'm not using `GPPSignIn` in the login flow, it tells me that

> "User must be signed in to use the native sharebox."

Is there any way to configure the GPPSignIn object with the existing access token?

Comment: Have you found any solution after all ? Facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: Please Share your solution if you found it

Comment: I ditched the webview and used the SDK to login.